# Get instances by class name in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I need to get all the instances in my stage according to an especific class name. I'm doing this:

```
var class_ref:Class = getDefinitionByName('fran.MyOwnClass') as Class;
var element;

for (var i:uint = 0; i < this.parent.numChildren; i++)
{
    element = this.parent.getChildAt(i);
    if (element is class_ref)
    {
        trace('Found element of class fran.MyOwnClass');
    }
}
```

But I want a better way (more efficiently, without checking all the MCs). Is it possible?

Comment: I can think of other ways of checking if it's the right class, but I don't think you can avoid the loop. Perhaps if you override `addChild()` of the container, you can do the check there?

Comment: @RIAstar Overriding is not what I want because I need to check what I say below to do stuff when I found elements. Or I didn't understand what you said (I'm already very newbie in AS3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can start tracking instances from the very beginning of you application life, I'd recommend simply add event listener:

```
// in document class constructor, before doing anything else
stage.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, stage_addedHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, stage_removedHandler);

private function stage_addedHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var obj:DisplayObject = event.target as DisplayObject;
    // do something, e.g. if (obj is MyClass) objCounter++;
}
...
```

If you can't track from the beginning, you can't avoid loops.. Just make them more optimized:

```
var n:int = container.numChildren;
while (n-- > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Overriding everywhere addChild() and others — that's simply impossible solution in real projects.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a list of all the MC's of a certain type by extending the container class and overriding its `addChild()`, `addChildAt()`, `removeChild()` and `removeChildAt()` functions.

```
public class MySprite extends Sprite {

    public var ownClasses:Vector.<MyOwnClass> = new Vector.<MyOwnClass>();

    override public function addChild(child:DisplayObject):DisplayObject {
        addOwnClass(child as MyOwnClass);
        return super.addChild(child);
    }

    override public function addChildAt(child:DisplayObject, index:int):DisplayObject {
        addOwnClass(child as MyOwnClass);
        return super.addChildAt(child, index);
    }

    private function addOwnClass(child:MyOwnClass):void {
        if (child) ownClasses.push(child);
    }

    override public function removeChild(child:DisplayObject):DisplayObject {
        removeOwnClass(child as MyOwnClass);
        return super.removeChild(child);
    }

    override public function removeChildAt(index:int):DisplayObject {
        removeOwnClass(getChildAt(index) as MyOwnClass);
        return super.removeChildAt(index);
    }

    private function removeOwnClass(child:MyOwnClass):void {
        if (child) {
            var i:int = ownClasses.indexOf(child);
            if (i != -1) ownClasses.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }

}
```

Using this class, every time a child is added, you check whether it's a `MyOwnClass` and if it is you add it to the `ownClasses` list. Similar for removing children.

Now you can simply access the list when you need it without looping over the MC's.

```
public class Main extends MySprite
{
    public function Main()
    {
        addChild(new Sprite());
        addChild(new MyOwnClass());
        trace(ownClasses);
    }
}
```

This will output `[object MyOwnClass]`